# UserControl Position

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls

I'm developing a WPF application, and I have created a custom usercontrol because I need to create instances of it, on the main window. So, this is how I create a new instance:

```
        var MyCard = new vCard();
        MainGrid.Children.Add(MyCard);
        Grid.SetColumn(MyCard, 1);
        Grid.SetRow(MyCard, 0);
```

But I need to place every one in order, so, how can I set the X & Y position of each one. I've tried creating a method in my usercontrol to set the margin property, example:

```
    public void SetX(double X)
    {
        double  Y =this.Margin.Top;            
        this.Margin = new Thickness(X, Y, 0, 0);            
    }
```

But, it's not working. Is there another way to do it?

Comment: If you want to perform arbitrary X,Y positioning within the Grid cell, try putting a Canvas at that grid location, then use the Canvas.Left and Canvas.Top attached properties to position the controls within the Canvas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An often neglected control is the [UniformGrid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.uniformgrid.aspx).

```
<UniformGrid Name="MainGrid" Rows="3" Columns="2"/>
```

Proceed to add the `UserControl` as you were before.

```
var MyCard = new vCard();
MainGrid.Children.Add(MyCard);
```

This will provide a nice and evenly distributed container for your items. If you want to adjust the spacing between items there are couple ways to do it, with the easiest being the adjustment of the `Margin` property on your `UserControl` itself.

```
<UserControl Margin="8" ... />
```

Answer (score 3):

When you add your control to a `Grid` container, you should set its position by setting `Column` and `Row`.

In order to do that, you will want to configure your grid to have the number of rows and columns necessary for adding your new user controls.

Answer (score 1):

I would make an `ObservableCollection` of the objects and place them inside a stack panel. That way you can add/remove/order the user controls. Then you could just do the set up the size inside of the stacks.